# How to link a comment to a single post in django?

Tags: python, django, view

I have a problem which I want to help me solve.
I have a "Post" with comments included but, when I comment a "Post" the comment I made in "Post 1" appears in "Post 2" and in all "Posts" and I want to link the comment to a single post, I've been looking for solutions but I have not been able to make it work.

EDIT I ADDED MY **post/models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
   autor = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   description = models.TextField()
   likes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
   created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
   files = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_location, validators=
                   [validate_file_extension])
   post_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Book_Type_Choices)
   tags = TaggableManager()
```

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='cooments')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
   post= get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = CommentForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          comment = form.save(commit=False)
          comment.post= post
          comment.user = request.user
          comment.save()
          return redirect('post_detail', slug=post.slug)
   else:
       form = CommentForm()
   return render(request, 'comments/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form':form})
```

my **add_comment.html**, this code fragment is included on my **post_detail.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=post.pk %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{form.as_p}}
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Comentar">
</form>
```

my **book_detail.html**

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 comment" style="text-align: center;">

    <!-- HERE IS WHERE I INCLUDE THE add_comment.html -->

    {% include 'comments/add_comment_to_post.html' %}
  </div>
{% for comment in comments %}
{% if user.is_authenticated or comment.approved_comment %}
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
      <div class="media-body">
          <div class="well well-lg">
            <div class="avatar">
              <img src="{{comment.user.profile.pic.thumbnail.url}}" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="">
            </div>
              <h4 class="media-heading text-uppercase reviews">{{comment.user.get_full_name}} </h4>
              <ul class="media-date text-uppercase reviews list-inline">
                <li>{{comment.created_date}}</li>
              </ul>
              <p class="media-comment">
                  {{comment.text}}
              </p>
              <a class="btn btn-info btn-circle text-uppercase" href="#" id="reply"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Reply</a>
              <a class="btn btn-warning btn-circle text-uppercase" data-toggle="collapse" href="#replyOne"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> 2 comments</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
{% empty %}
  <p>No hay comentarios que mostrar :(</p>
{% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how I can make comments work? Thanks!

Comment: Add the definition of your `Post` model as well. Current implementation suggests that you are not saving the relationship anywhere.

Comment: Looks like your `cooments` [sic] are linked by the ForeignKey to a `Book` and not to a `Post`.

Comment: Are you importing Post in your Comment model definition?

Comment: Add Comment ForeignKey to Post

Answer (score 2):

In the comment model try to remove the unique=False

Change

```
class Comment(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
```

to

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User) # remove unique=False
```

Do the above and take it from there